# Как работает #define?

Tags: c#, препроцессор

Не могу понять, как работает `#define`. Понимаю только, что при проверке с помощью `#if` будет выполняться или не выполнять код, в зависимости от того прописанный ли ранее `#define`, хорошо, но вопрос вот в чем, при компиляции эти строки в которых:

```
    #if TEXT  
        ...
    #endif
```

Они убираются или все таки идет проверка как с простым `if()`?

Comment: Бесследно убираются. Поиск и обработка подобных директив — это отдельный этап, выполняемый ещё до передачи текста программы компилятору.

Comment: то есть при дисассемблировании код который попал в неактивную #define не будет виден?

Comment: Да, как будто этого кода вообще не было в c/cpp/h-файле.

Comment: Воу, я тут про с-шарп говорил

Comment: .../cs-файле. Это препроцессор, он везде работает одинаково — перед компилятором и прозрачно для него.

Comment: в cpp ним можно и константы делать

Comment: @k0vpack, но в скомпилированном бинарнике этой константы не будет, вместо нее будут явно подставлены данные